# Django Video Encoding package not converting videos

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

hey guys I am trying to make the django-video-encoding package work with my code, but it doesn't seem to be converting the videos. I have followed exactly as per the documentation. Can someone help with checking the code I have if I missed anything??

This is the link to the package: https://github.com/escaped/django-video-encoding
Can anyone tell me where I went wrong? I couldn't see any tutorials or much info regarding this package but it seems like its the only one there.

I have given the path to ffmpeg like this (am not sure whether its the right way to provide path). this is in settings.

```
VIDEO_ENCODING_FFMPEG_PATH = "c:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe"
```

in my signals.py I have this.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=VideoPost)
def convert_video(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    enqueue(tasks.convert_all_videos, instance._meta.app_label, instance._meta.model_name, instance.pk)
    print('Done converting!')
```

and this prints after I upload a video, but the conversion does not happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to recreate but everything seems smooth to me. I didn't point the `ffmpeg` location though as I set it up in the PATH instead. Try to to set the `ffmpeg` as global(system) variable instead.

Comment: Can it be the problem with my settings? how I have my django-rq  works? Also can you tell me what you meant by ffmpeg as global variable? I didn't get you.

Comment: I mean to add ffmpeg to the PATH in windows. https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/20495/how-do-i-set-up-and-use-ffmpeg-in-windows here is how. 

I think `django-rq` works correctly since that you are seeing your print. The only error comes from ffmpeg.

Comment: Oh...yes!
Thanks..That was the issue.!